# Get JSON array data by field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get JSON data by field name like this `data.name` and it return the desired data, but I have 25 fields in the array and I want to make this dynamically, using `data + "." + variable`, when I alert it returns `[Object object].name`, so how I can make it executable?

I tried many ways but all failed, please help me doing this.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "Get",
  url: "/Home/Report_Data",
  datatype: "json",
  dataSrc: "",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: {
    'Arrnagement': Arrnagement
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var result = getElementsById("LD_name LD_Loan_Type LD_id LD_Full_Name_AR LD_GENDER LD_BIRTH_INCORP_DATE LD_PS_MOTHER_NAME LD_Street_AR LD_TEL_MOBILE LD_EMPLOY_STATUS_D LD_EMPLYRS_Name LD_MARITAL_STATUS LD_PS_PL_OF_BIR_AR LD_wifeName LD_Effective_Interest_Rate LD_Contract_amount LD_Repayment_Amount LD_Sector_name LD_NUM_REPAYMENTS LD_Loan_Maturity LD_Orig_Contract_Date LD_Loan_CCY LD_Arrangement LD_COLLATERAL_TYPE LD_Description LD_COLLATERAL_VALUE LD_COLLATERAL_Currency LD_GUARANTOR_ID LD_NATIONALITY LD_G_Full_Name_En LD_G_DATE_OF_BIRTH LD_G_PLACE_OF_BIRTH LD_G_MOTHER_NAME_EN LD_HOUSING_LOAN_AREA_CLASS LD_HOUSING_PROPERTY_NATURE LD_HOUSING_LOAN_PURPOSE LD_HOUSING_PROPERTY_AREA");
    var jid;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      jid = (result[i].id.substring(3));
      var resulting = data[0].jid;
      alert(resulting);
      if (result[i].innerHTML = data[0].jid != "undefined") {
        result[i].innerHTML = data[0].jid;
      } else {
        result[i].innerHTML = "";
      }
    }

//jid = name;
//data[0].name returns "Joun"
//data[0]+"."+jid returns [object object].name but i need it to return "Joun"
```

Comment: `for in` and `for of` might help you on this one. `For in` returning the keys and `for of` the values. Also note that you can access property of object as an array. `myObject.key` is mostly the same as `myObject["key"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Zyigh it didn't work for me bacause I cant make myObject[0,"key"]

Comment: Andreas thx it helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I changed the dot notation while accessing the object property.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/Home/Report_Data",
            datatype: "json",
            dataSrc: "",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { 'Arrnagement': Arrnagement },
            success: function (data) {

                var result = getElementsById("LD_name LD_Loan_Type LD_id LD_Full_Name_AR LD_GENDER LD_BIRTH_INCORP_DATE LD_PS_MOTHER_NAME LD_Street_AR LD_TEL_MOBILE LD_EMPLOY_STATUS_D LD_EMPLYRS_Name LD_MARITAL_STATUS LD_PS_PL_OF_BIR_AR LD_wifeName LD_Effective_Interest_Rate LD_Contract_amount LD_Repayment_Amount LD_Sector_name LD_NUM_REPAYMENTS LD_Loan_Maturity LD_Orig_Contract_Date LD_Loan_CCY LD_Arrangement LD_COLLATERAL_TYPE LD_Description LD_COLLATERAL_VALUE LD_COLLATERAL_Currency LD_GUARANTOR_ID LD_NATIONALITY LD_G_Full_Name_En LD_G_DATE_OF_BIRTH LD_G_PLACE_OF_BIRTH LD_G_MOTHER_NAME_EN LD_HOUSING_LOAN_AREA_CLASS LD_HOUSING_PROPERTY_NATURE LD_HOUSING_LOAN_PURPOSE LD_HOUSING_PROPERTY_AREA");

                var responseData = data[0];
                var jid;
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    jid = (result[i].id.substring(3));
                    var resulting = responseData[jid];
                    alert(resulting);
                    if (responseData[jid]) {
                        result[i].innerHTML = responseData[jid];
                    }
                    else {
                        result[i].innerHTML = "";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of help! You can mark it as accepted answer then. :D @IbrahimSalameg

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `data[0][jid]`, we can give a variable in brackets also inorder to get the data

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

If do `foo.bar` you are getting a property with the name 'bar' on object foo. If you have some variable `const bar = "qux"` and you want to access property on some object with the same name as `bar` value /"qux"/ you just need to use square brackets - `foo [bar]`, which will be the same as calling `foo.qux`; So, in your case you just need to use `data[0][jid]` instead of `data [0].jid`, supposing `jid` contains a string that is also a key in `data[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `data[0][variableName]` and this will return the data you want. for example. If data had a json string `[{ "Name" : "Jane Doe"}]` You could execute it like this.

```
var variableName = "Name";
console.log(data[0][variableName])
```

This would return "Jane Doe".
if you have your field names in an array you can loop through them using `$.each` or a `for loop`. 
For example say your json string is `[{"First_Name" : "Jane", "Last_Name" : "Doe", "Age" : 32}]` you could get all the values from the json string doing this.

```
var FieldNames = ["First_Name" , "Last_Name", "Age"]
$.each(FieldNames, function(i,item) {
    console.log(data[0][item])
}
```

OR

```
var FieldNames = ["First_Name" , "Last_Name", "Age"]
for(var i = 0; i < FieldNames.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[0][FieldNames[i]])
}
```

Comment: also returns undefined ! :(

Comment: @IbrahimSalameh this should work if the field name is exactly the same as the variable content.